# Authorize Attribute Does Not Work on Azure With OWIN

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have migrated a web application that runs in a Windows Azure cloud service from the default Membership system from the MVC 4 template to the new OWIN-based ASP.NET Identity provider.

The application relies heavily on roles, which for some reason have stopped working on Azure since the upgrade.

My controllers or actions are decorated with `[Authorize]`. This works fine, except when I specify a role `[Authorize(Roles = "User.Test")]` and run it in the Azure compute emulator. Now I will get an infinite redirects to the login page and back (I'm signed in, but for some reason it doesn't accept the role).
Interestingly, if I debug/run the web project directly (so not using the Azure emulator), it all works fine.

Any ideas on how to get this working on Azure as well? I have not had this behavior with anything else yet, so it's kind of left me clueless.

**Update November 26, 2013**

I have discovered similar behavior with the default MVC 5 template in VS2013. Please see this [forum thread on ASP.NET](http://forums.asp.net/t/1952572.aspx) for steps how to reproduce this problem without Azure.

Comment: Have you checked that the database that you use in Azure has the right rows in the AspNetUserRoles and AspNetRoles connected to the users in the AspNetUsers table?

Comment: Authorize Attribute and User.IsInRole are case sensitive while comparing.

Comment: @OlavNybø, yes this is all correct.

Comment: @jd4u, I'm aware of this. Case is exactly the same.

Comment: Changes to role of current user requires your to recreate ClaimsIdentity to work for subsequent request. Role check is done based on ClaimsIdentity.Claims which are populated while Authentication process.

Comment: try logout after you visit the "Role" action and Login before going to "About" action.

Comment: OK, that actually works in the default MVC5 project, but not in my Azure cloud service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, for some reason I caused this whole mess myself by using prereleases of the Owin and Identity libraries from MyGet.

Removing all the packages and installing the stable builds fixed all my problems.

Answer (score 0):

This one did the trick for me:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="RoleManager" /> <!-- <<<<< -->
```